# Return the biggest value less than one from a numpy vector

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy vector in python and I want to find the index of the max value of the vector with the condition that it is less than one. I have as an example the following:

```
temp_res = [0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.99, 1.2, 1.5, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.01, 0.12, 0.56, 0.89, 0.23, 0.56, 0.78]
temp_res = np.asarray(temp_res)
indices = np.where((temp_res == temp_res.max()) & (temp_res < 1))
```

However, what I tried always return an empty matrix since those two conditions cannot be met. HU want to return as final result the index = 3 which correspond to 0.99 the biggest value that it is less than 1. How can I do so?

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: @eugenhu For arrays yes but still that's confusing and not recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
np.where(temp_res == temp_res[temp_res < 1].max())[0]
```

Example:

```
In [49]: temp_res
Out[49]: 
array([0.9 , 0.8 , 0.7 , 0.99, 1.2 , 1.5 , 0.1 , 0.5 , 0.1 , 0.01, 0.12,
       0.56, 0.89, 0.23, 0.56, 0.78])

In [50]: np.where(temp_res == temp_res[temp_res < 1].max())[0]
    ...: 
Out[50]: array([3])
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to perform the `max()` function after filtering your array:

```
temp_res = np.asarray(temp_res)
temp_res[temp_res < 1].max()

Out[60]: 0.99
```

If you want to find all the indexes, here is a more genera approach:

```
mask = temp_res < 1
indices = np.where(mask)
maximum = temp_res[mask].max()
max_indices = np.where(temp_res == maximum)
```

Example:

```
...: temp_res = [0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 1, 0.99, 0.99, 1.2, 1.5, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.01, 0.12, 0.56, 0.89, 0.23, 0.56, 0.78]
...: temp_res = np.asarray(temp_res)
...: mask = temp_res < 1
...: indices = np.where(mask)
...: maximum = temp_res[mask].max()
...: max_indices = np.where(temp_res == maximum)
...: 

In [72]: max_indices
Out[72]: (array([4, 5]),)
```

Comment: `argmax()` will return the index on the filtered array, and only the first occurrence...

Comment: @eugenhu No. If there is an entry > 1 before the first 0.99, the result is wrong.

Comment: @liliscent Yes, I understand what you mean, just updated. And thanks for the comment.